# Defining props of a single page Vue component using v-for

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, coffeescript, slim-lang

I am trying to render a Vue component, iterating through an array of data fetched thru Ajax, all inside a Rails app.

I have the Slim template (index.html.slim) for the index page as follows. This makes use of a custom_form_item component, where items is the collection of custom forms data from Rails and each item in it is a component.

```
- content_for :head do
  = javascript_pack_tag "index_listing" 
  = stylesheet_pack_tag "index_listing" 

div.container data-behavior="vue"
  <custom_form_item v-for="item in items" v-bind:item="item" v-bind:key="item.id"></custom_form_item>
```

This loads index_listing.js.coffee which is present in javascript/packs. The created event is used to load the data for items.

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import CustomFormItem from '../components/custom_form_item.vue'

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)

Vue.component('custom_form_item', CustomFormItem)

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', ->
  index_list_vm = new Vue(
    el: '[data-behavior="vue"]'
    data: () ->
      return {
        items: []
      }
    created: () ->
      console.log "inside created()"
      this.loadItems()
    methods: {
      loadItems: () ->
        self = this
        console.log "inside loadIems()"
        url = '...'
        self.$http.get(url).then((result) ->
          console.log "Got: "+result.data
          self.items = result.data
        )
    }
  )
)

Turbolinks.dispatch("turbolinks:load")
```

The component is defined as below. It has a delete button using a component method to remove the respective item from items upon clicking.

```
<template>
  <div class="custom_form_list_item">
    <label for="item_id">ID</label>
    <input id="item_id" v-model="item.id" readonly>
    <br/>
    <label for="item_name">Name</label>
    <input id="item_name" v-model="item.name" readonly>
    <br/>
    <label for="item_version">Version</label>
    <input id="item_version" v-model="item.version" readonly>
    <br/>
    <label for="item_label">Label</label>
    <input id="item_label" v-model="item.label" readonly>
    <br/>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <button type="button" class="btn-warning btn-sm" v-on:click="redirToEditURL(item.id)">
         <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn-danger btn-sm" v-on:click="deleteForm(item.id)">
         <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    redirToEditURL: function(formid) {
      let url = ...
      window.location = url
    },
    deleteItem: function(key) {
      this.$delete(this.items, key);
    },
    deleteForm: function(formid) {
      let url = '...';
      let deleteListItem = this.deleteItem;
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "DELETE",
      }).done(deleteListItem.bind(this, formid));
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
...
</style>
```

When I render this I get the following warning and component is rendered without any data (item.* values present in the template)

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "item". Expected Object, got Array.

found in

---> <CustomFormItem> at app/javascript/components/custom_form_item.vue
       <Root>
```

Also the Vue dev tools shows this as Props,
[image: vue-dev-tools-props]

item in Props is actually items rather than one from the loop (item in items).

**How can I get the right props for the component, i.e. pass item from items correctly into the component while populating items from an external source via ajax?**

**Fixed!** Solution: self.items = result.data.data (the result was passed as an JSON object {data: ...} by rails, which was result.data.data.

Comment: convert data as object while binding with component

Comment: This is because your server is sending back An array of Objects. You cannot just send an object back from rails.

Comment: It worked when I directly populated it while using the component in the page as follows,

      <custom_form_item v-for="item in #{ @custom_forms.to_json(except: [:created_at, :updated_at]) }" v-bind:item="item" v-bind:key="item.id"></custom_form_item>

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
<div v-for="item in items">
   <custom_form_item :item="item" :key="item.id"></custom_form_item>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work. Still gives the same result. Props.item is an Array with two items in it (I have two objects in items).

Comment: props inner object is not render. so you split two props `:object :required`.

Comment: @Parthan It's useful for your requirement.?? If any other solution you have plz share with me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Solution: self.items = result.data.data (the result was passed as an JSON object {data: ...} by rails, which was result.data.data.